# How to read line by line from file

Tags: c

I want to create a function `read_ins` that reads only the first line from a file.

I want my code to read the second line in the second call and third line in third call and so on...

Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{
    char *singleIns; // for reading from Instruction FILE
    char *instructions[3][3]; // all the Instructions

    singleIns = malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
    int i =0,j=0;

    // Read one Instruction (32bit)
    while (i<3){
        j=0;
        while(j<3){
            read_ins(singleIns); 
            instructions[i][j] = singleIns;
            j++;
        }
        i++;

    }

    printf("%s",instructions[0][0]);
    return 0;
}


void read_ins(char ins[]){
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads text until newline
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", ins);

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it. Reading a line should be a separate function from opening the file and closing the file. Also, you don't need `fscanf` to read a line -- `fgets` would be better.

Comment: Each time you open the file, where do you think you program starts reading from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, your function `read_ins` is always outputting the first line of your file `program.txt`.

This is because each time you open the file using `fopen`, the read cursor is starting from the beginning of the file.

To change this behavior, you should open the file and give the FILE* as an argument of your function `read_ins` and leave it open until the end of the main.

Something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Open file
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

    // Read Instructions (32bit)
    while (i<3){
        read_ins(fptr, ins);
    }

    // Close file
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}


void read_ins(FILE* fptr, char ins[]){
    // reads text until newline
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", ins);
}
```

As the new `read_ins` is only one line, you can get rid of it...

Or, you can open and close the file in `read_ins` but you need to specify the number of the line you want to return. And read the file until you found the correct line. However, this is quite expensive as you open and close a file everytime..